# Copy data from S3 to redshift - CSV

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, copy, amazon-redshift

I am trying to load data from csv files located in S3 to Amazon Redshift. For few `nvarchar(10)` columns it is adding additional dots before and after which is increasing length of the string and failing with error:

> "String length exceeds DDL length" Value: .........R0496......

But when I checked data in the source database and CSV file data is without dots (R0496), not able to identify the reason for adding additional dots. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

This is the command I am currently executing for copying data into table:

```
copy <schema>.<table_name> from 's3://<bucket>/<key>'
iam_role default
IGNOREBLANKLINES TRIMBLANKS
delimiter '|' region 'eu-west-1' IGNOREHEADER 1 CSV;
```

Comment: It might be due to non-printing characters.  Run the data through od or xd and see it there.